# Join a CTE (having number of business days) with a query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a CTE table with no. of businessdays calculated, and  a separate query where i would like this CTE table to be joined and reading in wkdaysinmonth,wkdaystodate but i am kind of lost how to join these two together and and get results:

```
 with dates as(
        select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
        dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
        convert(date,getdate()) as today
    ), holidays as (
        select *
        from (values ('20181224'),('20181225'),('20181231')) x (holiday)
     )
    ,holidaycount as (
        select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
            sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
        from dates
        join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
    )
    ,daycounts as(
        select dates.*,

           (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
          -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinmonth,

           (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
          -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
          -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodate

        from dates
        cross join holidaycount
    )
```

-------------code 2-------------

I tried something like this but its not working :

```
with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
), holidays as (
    select *
    from (values ('20181224'),('20181225'),('20181231')) x (holiday)
 )
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
,daycounts as(
    select dates.*,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinmonth,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodate

    from dates
    cross join holidaycount
)
```

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

output columns needed are:

```
inv_date,SALES_ID,CL_KEY,weekdaysinmonth
```

Any help is appreciated..
Thankyou

Comment: Please add the table definitions, some sample data, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

because your join is referencing a table alias declared in the parenthesis generating table `o1`

I recommend you create a [calendar table](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-data-techniques-in-sql/), rather than dynamically generating the dates. You can have fields for holidays, `wkdaysinmonth` and `wkdaystodate` can be pre-calculated and you only have one table to join.

---

A note on your code style; you should stick to one style of capitalisation in your code, it makes the query much easier to read. Sometimes you are using `ALL_CAPS`, other times `all_lower` interchangeably for both table and field names.

The common style I see for SQL Server is:

```
Capitalised_Table_Names.all_lower_field_names
```

Even if you don't like that style, define your own style but be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you are trying to reference an "inner" table in the "outer" query.  You can only do the opposite.   You also have a `ON` without a `JOIN`.

In short, what you have is:

```
SELECT ... FROM (Derived Table) o1 ON o1.Column=c.Column
```

Not only is there no JOIN for that ON clause, but the alias `c` does not exist in the outer query.

You need to do all your relating of `c` to the other tables inside the derived table itself and not in the outer query.